# Running node creation from another url?

Tags: 7

I have a node called "survey". To create one, you go to:

```
/node/add/survey
```

I want to make a new url at: /make-survey, which must show exactly what you would see at /node/add/survey

What is the easiest way to do this in Drupal 7?

**Follow up question:**

Once I got the paths right, I now need to change the title. Currently it is "Create Survey" ... i would prefer if it's just "Survey"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in aliasing built into the path module:

- Navigate to `/admin/config/search/path/add`
- Add `/node/add/survey` to **Existing system path**
- Add `/make-survey` to **Path alias**
- Click **Save**

The new `/make-survey` alias will now map to your survey add form.

Comment: That solves that problem beautifully, but how do I then chane the title. Currently it is "Create Survey" ... i would prefer if it's just "Survey"

Comment: A path alias displays whatever title the target path has. I believe there's a module for overriding Titles on a per path (or route) basis, but the name escapes me at the moment.